# Flask-sqlalchemy limit offset pagination performance for Oracle

Tags: python, oracle, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am working on Flask application and we are using Flask-sqlalchemy to communicate the the oracle database. Unfortunately, we have the performance issue. Here are the details:

- Oracle database
- optimize_limits=True is set to True in the configuration
- Table we are querying has 800000 rows
- The table has 19 columns and the types are:

[image]

- flask-sqlalchemy version is 2.5.1

Things I tried:

1. Using the standard limit/offset approach. Here is the code:

> books = Books.query.order_by(desc(id)).offset(200000).limit(10000).all()

In this case it can take 26.7 seconds to retrieve 10000 rows with offset 200000.

2. Using paginate method of the query. Here is the code:

> books = Books.query.paginate(20, 10000, error_out=False)

In this case it can take 30 seconds to retrieve 10000 rows for page number 20.

3. Implementing cursors manually. Here is the code:

> books = Books.query.order_by(desc(id)).filter(Books.id >= 1315200).limit(10000).all()

In this case it can take 30.65 seconds to retrieve 10000 rows.

This is all extremely slow since this is exposed by an API used by Angular UI. Does anyone have suggestions for performance improvements?
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Can you change `arraysize`? See https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/oracle.html#options-consumed-by-the-sqlalchemy-cx-oracle-dialect-outside-of-the-driver

Comment: For background reference see the cx_Oracle documentation [Tuning Fetch Performance](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/tuning.html#tuning-fetch-performance).

Comment: @ChristopherJones thank you very much! now the retrieval time is between 7-8 seconds. I read about `prefetchrows` parameter in the documentation you sent. I think this would improve the performance further. Is there a way to set this with flask-sqlchemy ?